# Fourier Transform of a PDE in 2 spatial variables.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am given the equation

$\partial_t u = \partial_x^2 u + x \partial_y u,$

with initial data

$u(0,x,y) = u_0(x,y),$

and I wish to apply the Fourier Transform(FT) in both spatial variables to the equation. By using the properties of the FT I computed the following transformed equation:

$\partial_t \hat{u} = - \xi_1^2 \hat{u} - \xi_2 \partial_{\xi_1} \hat{u},$

with corresponding initial data

$\hat{u}(0,\xi_1,\xi_2) = \hat{u_0}(\xi_1,\xi_2)$.

Is this the correct application of the FT? If not some assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks OK to me.