# Classifying a 2nd order linear partial differential operator.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-operators

As a follow up to: [Fourier Transform of a PDE in 2 spatial variables.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1504535/fourier-transform-of-a-pde-in-2-spatial-variables)

I wish to classify the right side of the equation

$\partial_t u = \partial_x^2 u + x \partial_y u,$

viewed as an operator. From what I understand, the principal part of the operator is $\partial_x^2 $ with principal symbol $-\xi^2$, and in $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{0\}, \implies -\xi^2 \neq 0$ which suggests that the operator is elliptic, is this the case?

Comment: The spatial operator looks parabolic to me, because there are two spatial variables and there is no $y$ derivative in the principal part.

Comment: This is my thought as well as the equation is similar to the heat equation so I am wondering what my error is. I am familiar with the methods of classifying second-order linear PDEs with constant coefficients, but I am unsure what to do with the term involving the y variable.